# keeping track of indices change in numpy.reshape

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, indexing, reshape

While using `numpy.reshape` in Python, is there a way to keep track of the change in indices?

For example, if a numpy array with the shape `(m,n,l,k)` is reshaped into an array with the shape `(m*n,k*l)`; is there a way to get the initial index (`[x,y,w,z]`) for the current `[X,Y]` index and vice versa?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes there is, it's called [`raveling`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel_multi_index.html#numpy-ravel-multi-index) and [`unraveling`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unravel_index.html#numpy-unravel-index) the index. For example you have two arrays:

```
import numpy as np

arr1 = np.arange(10000).reshape(20, 10, 50)
arr2 = arr.reshape(20, 500)
```

say you want to index the `(10, 52)` (equivalent to `arr2[10, 52]`) element but in `arr1`:

```
>>> np.unravel_index(np.ravel_multi_index((10, 52), arr2.shape), arr1.shape)
(10, 1, 2)
```

or in the other direction:

```
>>> np.unravel_index(np.ravel_multi_index((10, 1, 2), arr1.shape), arr2.shape)
(10, 52)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't keep track of it, but you can calculate it.  The original `m x n` is mapped onto the new `m*n` dimension, e.g.  `n*x+y == X`.  But we can verify with a couple of multidimensional ravel/unravel functions (as answered by `@MSeifert`).

```
In [671]: m,n,l,k=2,3,4,5
In [672]: np.ravel_multi_index((1,2,3,4), (m,n,l,k))
Out[672]: 119
In [673]: np.unravel_index(52, (m*n,l*k))
Out[673]: (2, 12)
```